# Extract particular frames from a video without loading the whole video

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video encoded with H264, size 1.4 GB and I only need some part of the frames in the middle.

Can I use ffmpeg to extract part of the frames from the middle of the video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The `-ss` switch to `ffmpeg` seeks to a given time.  The `-vframes` flag records a specific number of frames.

```
$ ffmpeg -i myvideo.avi -ss 00:01:00 -vframes 20 myclip.avi
```

Should get 20 frames from 1 minute and onwards and put them in myclip.avi

If you want individual images set `-vframes` to 1 and save as a .png file for example.

Comment: if you place -ss *before* -i then it will be a whole lot faster.